# Europe, flight access refused because of expired ID (proof of renewal)

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, denied-boarding

A friend of mine tried to take a flight from France to Spain last week but his ID was expired (French ID), it is commonly known that even though the ID is expired it is still valid for some times (4 or 5 years apparently).

Though he renewed it a few days before taking the flight so he got a paper proving that he did it and that is supposedly mean to avoid this kind of situation.

Was the person who denied him the access to the plane right ?

Comment: What type of ID was it? A CNI or a passport? How old is your friend? The rule is not that is valid for 5 years after expiration, the rule is that some CNIs have had their validity extended from 10 to 15 years, but not all countries accept that. See https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Archives/Archives-des-actualites/2016-Actualites/Date-de-validite-des-cartes-d-identite-prudence-lors-de-vos-voyages-a-l-etranger for details. Having actually renewed the CNI (i.e. having received the new one) will address the situation, not just having requested it. Airline personnel usually err on the side of caution.

Comment: Absolutely. The lack of valid ID = they have no idea who you are = they should not allow you in.

Comment: @jcaron A classic French ID card, not a passport, an ID, but he was under 18 when he got his card so the extension is probably not valid for him, though still the problem about the paper that proves the renewal and should replace a real ID until he gets the new one (at least that's what the council told me when I made a passport request, they gave me a similar paper that I could use as a subsitute).

Comment: That paper is valid only in France.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known situation and the airline was right, despite the Schengen code.

> He renewed it a few days before taking the flight so he got a paper proving that he did it and that is supposedly mean to avoid this kind of situation.

Officially, he didn't. You renew your ID as soon as you get a new printed document with a new expiration date that is in the future. Some countries allow `naive` procedures for renewing IDs in order to save money. The idea is that if you didn't change your appearence significantly you can continue using the old photo ID, and government can save on the cost of giving you a new ID, which they pay for.

I know a number of cases of rejected passengers when their ID is extended by the government to up to 15 years, as explained in the [French Ministry Of Interior Affairs](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Archives/Archives-des-actualites/2016-Actualites/Date-de-validite-des-cartes-d-identite-prudence-lors-de-vos-voyages-a-l-etranger). Not all foreign government accept this practice. `Espagne` appars in

> Pays dont les autorités n’ont pas officiellement transmis leur position quant à l’acceptation de la carte d’identité dont la validité est prolongée de 5 ans
>
> Countries whose authorities have not officially transmitted their position on the acceptance of the identity card, the validity of which is extended by 5 years

That is trash when crossing the border, even if your local authorities allow and it is socially acceptable. An expired document is not a document, it's like it doesn't exist.

One might blame the government officer having opted to issue a sheet of paper rather than a new paper/plastic ID.

One consideration: according to Schengen rules, there *theoretically* should be no systematic ID check on travelers. In fact, this occurs on land borders. The truth is that the PNR regulation in Europe requires passengers to be systematically identified when they *board* a plane, regardless of their destination. Their name is kept for 6 months in the airline database should government authorities issue an investigation to retrieve the list. After that, they must be anonymized.

Comment: Well the only person he can blame is himself, he paid the price for his mistake, as I quite often travel by plane and have not been asked for my ID every time I was wondering who was wrong here, thanks !

Comment: Any references for the bit about "PNR regulation in Europe requires passengers to be systematically identified when they board a plane"? Most airlines/airports don't check your ID when boarding an intra-Schengen flight. Those who do (like EasyJet) supposedly do it mainly to prevent unauthorized resale of tickets.